# Create ordered list using data returned from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

I followed a lot of tutorials about this but can't have this working. I want to create an ordered list with a manipulated data received via API. I create a factory for each WebService I need to ask.

*Factory:*

```
angular.module('aparcare').factory('Items', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function (fields) {
            return $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "the-url-to-the-api",
                data: "field=2&anotherfield=4",
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data.Items;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

*Controller:*

```
angular.module('app').controller('ItemController', function ($http, $rootScope, $window, $scope, Items) {
    var controller = this;
    controller.items = [];
    //Call the API
    Items.get().then(function (response) {        
        //Transform array of objects in associative id => object
        angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
            controller.items[item.ID] = item;
        });

    }, function (error) {
        console.log("Error ocurred on API call");
    });
});
```

*Template*:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="select-entity">

    <li ng-repeat="item in controller.items">
        <a ng-click="controller.select_item(item.ID)">{{ item.DESCRIPTION }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Currently the order of logs are `1 3 2` not `1 2 3`

Comment: What exactly you mean by "can't have this working"?? do you get any error?

Comment: Problem with Angular (and most new frameworks) is that every example looks different. I always add the object to the $scope - $scope.items = []; What does your API return? Never had to loop through the items and create an array before - I just use the parsed JSON object.

Comment: How are you using controller in your view

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh sorry, This works, no errors, but the array is not filling, if I put a console log before, inside and afther the "then", the order of logs are 1 3 2 not 1 2 3, sorry for my bad english

Comment: @LeeWillis Willis I need to create an array with the info, can't manage the current return without it

Comment: @Satpal ng-controller="ItemController as controller". This part works as expected, is just the moment to fill the array when I have problems

Comment: @Jax700303 Typo error while transforming the names to a common sense names

Comment: use $scope.controller.items = response; to fill the list for repeater (if response is the returned array), don't use angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
            controller.items[item.ID] = item;
        });

Comment: @Lloople Use `controller.items = response;` without `angular.forEach`

Comment: @Satpal Anyway, if I do this, I will need the response items in asssociative array (intern, not in the view). How can I create that associative array without looping inside .then()? or what is the best practice?

Comment: @Lloople, Why do you need to create `asssociative array`? there no use of it as per your example. Each item has all the data which will be required.

Comment: @Satpal I created it already, I discover I can use angular.forEach inside the .then just for fill a controller property, but not something used in the view. I need as associative because when someone click on a item, I need to get it somehow

Comment: @Lloople, Just try it out mate believe me it will work same as item as `item.ID` property which you want. Just log it once what you get when you pass `item`

Comment: @Satpal I think I don't explain myself very well. When someone click an item, I get the code, and I need to search the item with that code. The unique way I can imagine is any kind of pointer, and if it's inside an associative array I can get it using items[code], because items[code] contains the item itself, the code is used to find it. You know a better way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79399/discussion-between-satpal-and-lloople).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create an associative array.

```
Items.get().then(function (items) { 
    //Assign items directly
    controller.items = items;
}, function (error) {

});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/7hd9L1Lb/)</kbd>

Comment: Removing the angular.forEach and using your system to manage the items solved the problem and I'm sure this code is more optimized than mine! Thank you a lot

Comment: If your items array weren't sorted by your API, you could filter with angular like that: `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`